# "suffer from the tragedy of perfection" meaning

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

There's a line I saw on a movie.

The scenario is on a funeral, and one of the deceased's family members said that the deceased "did not suffer from the tragedy of perfection."  What does it mean?

Based on the translated subtitles, I roughly know it means the deceased was not a perfect person. But why?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. You *heard* the line *in* a movie.

Comment: @TRomano Could have been a subtitle

Comment: @Laurent Duval. It seems that the subtitles were not in English ("Based on the translated subtitles, I roughly know...") and the quoted phrase is in English. We'd still say "in", not "on".

Comment: It was English subtitles at first.                                                                       Then I shift to Chinese subtitles to find out what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A perfect funeral punchline**, mixing praise, empathy, and irony.

Funerals are occasions of hearing gentle words about the deceased (**praise**). Whatever the personality of the person. The lack of suffering is often evoked by the audience after a painful disease (**empathy**).

This line is to me a perfect example of **irony**, under the rhetoric form of the [litotes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/litotes), which states a point  by denying the opposite. A very polite way to say, with a lot of wit, that the deceased was far from perfect, had a lot of failings, and possibly lived quite happily in that situation.

Comment: I really really want to give you a thumbs up but I haven't reached the standard to do so:( Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jasmine Kuo Was the line from Dexter? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1242111/synopsis

Comment: WOW! It is.How do you know that?

Comment: I am a serial researcher:) Just want to know the actual sources for my next funeral ceremony. The punchline is so witty

Comment: LOL Is it Dexter's(the character) line?"Just want to know the actual sources for my next funeral ceremony. " Feels detached and funny

Comment: The quote is from Dexter, but it is Jimmy Smits character (Miguel Prado) in season 3 episode one. He says it at his brothers funeral while he is explaining to Dexter his love for his brother.

Answer (score 2):

The obsessive pursuit of "perfection" can indeed be a tragedy, because, roughly speaking, people are generally imperfect and refusing to accept
our own limitations (or other people unavoidable flaws) can lead to a miserable life of constant unsatisfaction.

You can find more details under the wikipedia entry for ["perfectionism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectionism_%28psychology%29).

You can also consider the well-known aphorism ["Perfect is enemy of good"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good).

Comment: I was told that it means the deceased made some (probably serious) mistakes in his life.When you say someone did not suffer from the tragedy of perfection.Does it mean that he or she doesn't care about being perfect or not even doesn't care about making a few mistakes?Thank you!